# Why JQuery .val() returns empty string?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

With script below, request to the server always sends empty string (even if value is not emtpty), where the data line is:

```
data: "{ 'folderName': '" + $(this).val() + "' }"
```

The html element under investigation is this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="searcher" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="classificationFolder" />
```

Script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".classificationFolder").each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Services/svcFolder.asmx/SearchFolders",
                    data: "{ 'folderName': '" + $(this).val() + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.Name,
                                label: item.Name + " " + item.Type
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
        });
    })
});
```

The reason that I select elements by css class selector ($(".classificationFolder")) is that, this control is a user control and used in the same page more than once. That is why I'm not using $("#searcher").

I tested the code In IE8 and Chrome 8.0.552.28 beta. This issue is arising in both of the browsers.

On the other hand, request is sent to the server, client received response successfuly and response is processed on the client.

So anyone has any idea why $(this).val() always returns empty string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a scope/context issue: `this` doesn't refer to the input element any more, but to the autocomplete.

Try storing `this` as a temporary variable:

```
$(".classificationFolder").each(function () {
        var input_reference = this;
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Services/svcFolder.asmx/SearchFolders",
                    data: "{ 'folderName': '" + $(input_reference).val() + "' }",
 ...
```

Comment: +1 No need for conjecture, you are correct about Scope.  But `this` in his case refers to the closest closure, probably the ajax options or the anonymous function inside the `source` parameter.

Comment: @AnreKR I mean the object passed to the `autocomplete` function, but @Stephen is probably more correct with his assessment.

Answer (score 1):

The `source` callback is not executed in the context of the element.
`this` is not what you think it is.

You need to save a reference to `this` in the outer `each` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `this` does not point to the input field. Isn't the `request` paramter of your callback function the value you are looking for?